# Alterar dinamicamente a cor de padrão de um texto em um listViewAdapter padrão?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-adapter, adapter

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
String[] hours = new String[]{
            "0:00 da madrugada",
            "0:30 da madrugada",
            "1:00 da madrugada",
            "1:30 da madrugada",
            "2:00 da madrugada",
            "2:30 da madrugada",
            "3:00 da madrugada",
            "3:30 da madrugada",
            "4:00 da madrugada",
            "4:30 da madrugada",
            "5:00 da madrugada",
            "5:30 da madrugada",
            "6:00 da manhã",
            "6:30 da manhã",
            "7:00 da manhã",
            "7:30 da manhã",
            "8:00 da manhã",
            "8:30 da manhã",
            "9:00 da manhã",
            "9:30 da manhã",
            "10:00 da manhã",
            "10:30 da manhã",
            "11:00 da manhã",
            "11:30 da manhã",
            "12:00 da tarde",
            "12:30 da tarde",
            "13:00 da tarde",
            "13:30 da tarde",
            "14:00 da tarde",
            "14:30 da tarde",
            "15:00 da tarde",
            "15:30 da tarde",
            "16:00 da tarde",
            "16:30 da tarde",
            "17:00 da tarde",
            "17:30 da tarde",
            "18:00 da noite",
            "18:30 da noite",
            "19:00 da noite",
            "19:30 da noite",
            "20:00 da noite",
            "20:30 da noite",
            "21:00 da noite",
            "21:30 da noite",
            "22:00 da noite",
            "22:30 da noite",
            "23:00 da noite",
            "23:30 da noite"
    };


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void alertDialogStartHour(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog  =   new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View viewDialog = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_horas,null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = alertdialog.create();
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        final ListView listView = viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.listViewHoras);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, hours);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                startHour = position;

                String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                textView_Hour.setText(itemValue);

                dialog.dismiss();

            }

        });

        dialog.setView(viewDialog);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

A minha intenção é poder manipular a cor a minha livre vontade. Isso porque, dependendo da hora do dia, como exemplo (12:00 da tarde), os textos com horários anteriores e que se apresentam em preto, fique na cor vermelha, indicando para o usuário que não é permitido selecionar aquele horário se caso o mesmo for clicado.

Comment: Tem de escrever um adapter.

Comment: Pois é, eu acho que é o jeito.....

Comment: Não é preciso amigo.... Dá para alterar dinamicamente. Veja a solução encontrada por mim na resposta...

Comment: Amigo, o que você fez não foi mais do que escrever uma Adapter, como sugeri no meu comentário. Apenas o fez de forma anónima( *anonymous class*).

Comment: É mas você não explicou que tipo de adapter eu tinha que fazer e nem de que forma né.... kkkkkk Ou seja, para mim a sua resposta deu a intender que o Adapter que eu tinha que fazer é um Adapter personalizado usando um layout personalizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quem possa interessar a solução é mais simples do que parece. Veja como como é fácil no meu código abaixo:

```
static final String[] hours = new String[]{
            "0:00 da madrugada","0:30 da madrugada","1:00 da madrugada","1:30 da madrugada",
            "2:00 da madrugada","2:30 da madrugada","3:00 da madrugada","3:30 da madrugada",
            "4:00 da madrugada","4:30 da madrugada","5:00 da madrugada","5:30 da madrugada",
            "6:00 da manhã","6:30 da manhã","7:00 da manhã","7:30 da manhã","8:00 da manhã",
            "8:30 da manhã","9:00 da manhã","9:30 da manhã","10:00 da manhã","10:30 da manhã",
            "11:00 da manhã","11:30 da manhã","12:00 da tarde","12:30 da tarde","13:00 da tarde",
            "13:30 da tarde","14:00 da tarde","14:30 da tarde","15:00 da tarde","15:30 da tarde",
            "16:00 da tarde","16:30 da tarde","17:00 da tarde","17:30 da tarde","18:00 da noite",
            "18:30 da noite","19:00 da noite","19:30 da noite","20:00 da noite","20:30 da noite",
            "21:00 da noite","21:30 da noite","22:00 da noite", "22:30 da noite","23:00 da noite",
            "23:30 da noite"
    };




    final ListView listView = viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.listViewHoras);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, hours){

                        /* 
                         * É só acrescentar este método e manipular da forma que você quiser 
                         * já que o método getView() percorre todo o meu array ''hours[]''
                         * e seta no TextView da posição (''position'').
                         *
                         */

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){

                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                        TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                        // Todos os textos aparecerão em vermelho //
                        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRedText));
                            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    startHour = position;

                                    String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                    textView_hora.setText(itemValue);

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });


                            /* 
                             * Exemplo de outra configuração > Por exemplo: Se eu quiser que apenas o primeiro
                             * apareça em vermelho:
                             *
                             * if(position == 1){
                             *
                             *      textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRedText));
                             *
                             * }else{
                             *
                             *      textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlackText));
                             * 
                             * }
                             *
                             */

                        return view;
                    }
```